# Static функции

Tags: c++

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, для чего в коде используют статические функции? Это вид оптимизации часто вызывающихся функций? или я не правильно понимаю... ?

Answer (score 4):

Независимые статические функции не могут быть вызваны из других модулей.

Comment: Вот этого я и ждал - спасибо mikillskegg!

Comment: Пожалуйста. На кнопочку нажимаем, ответ принимаем.

Answer (score 1):

ну собственно сам модификатор нужен для того чтобы можно было вызывать методы класса **до** того как будет создан сам класс + ещё пара мелочей.

наверно самые частые применения это

1. отложенное инстанцирование класса
       (например для [Singleton](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%E4%E8%ED%EE%F7%EA%E0_(%F8%E0%E1%EB%EE%ED_%EF%F0%EE%E5%EA%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%FF)))
2. набор методов которые нужно чётко
       отграничить (сказал глупо и не
       точно, потому пример: в java класс
       Math)
3. так же для разграничения области
       видимости (но это больше к "C"
       относится, так как в C++ есть
       `namespace`)

Comment: Про классы и про данные все понятно, мне функции статические интересны =)

Comment: @BESSONoff

**ну а что не понятно? **

можно заблокировать конструкторы а создание объекта вынести в статик метод (смотрим синглтон)

можно сделать так что бы функция была видна только в текущем файле